# Problems with MongoDB trying to deploy a Meteor App

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb, meteor, meteor-up

I have been setting up a server on a Digital Ocean droplet in order to host a couple of Meteor apps. I'm doing everything from scratch so I can learn as much as possible. I am trying to use "Meteor-Up" (mup) to deploy an app, but it is having problem communicating with MongoDB. When I run "mup setup" I get the following error:

```
Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[Gibson] - Installing Docker
[Gibson] - Installing Docker: SUCCESS
[Gibson] - Setting up Environment
[Gibson] - Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
[Gibson] - Copying MongoDB configuration
[Gibson] - Copying MongoDB configuration: SUCCESS
[Gibson] - Installing MongoDB
[Gibson] x Installing MongoDB: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mongodb (1e188b51b171446cd22d96f40ceab1e696019e5ac33ca713d78827246ae37ec8): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: bind: address already in use.
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
Digest: sha256:beff97308c36f7af664a1d04eb6ed09be1d14c17427065b2ec4b0de90967bb3f
Status: Image is up to date for mongo:latest
mongodb
c17e5ac9e9369b779da4aff639c16578dedbc7c357985f67d6e7b005d9cf3939
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I can't get from this any indication of what's going wrong. Is the problem with Mongo, Meteor, mup, or docker?

EDIT:

So far I understand from the message that "mup" is trying to connect to Mongo on port 27017 and is failing, I just don't understand why or how to fix it. I have a database that I want the app to connect to, which I moved onto the server from my local machine using mongodump and mongorestore.  The thing I can't solve is how to connect my meteor app to that mongo DB.

Comment: It says some other application is already using port 27017. As 2 apps cannot share the same port, you have 2 options - shut down the one which is already running (a mongod ?) or change dockerfiles to use different port.

Comment: But Alex, my understanding is that MongoDB always runs on port 27017 and multiple meteor applications are always able to access it. What don't I get?

Comment: When you run `mup setup` it installs docker, then installs mongodb container and tries to bind it to port 27017, fails, and report cause of the failure. What is not clear here?

Comment: I have had multiple meteor apps running on a single machine before - when I start (or deploy) one app, I don't have to stop or turn off MongoDB. The meteor app should be able find the existing database because it has the setting variable "MONGO_URL" set to "mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName".  But you are suggesting that i have to STOP mongod before I can deploy with mup. Which I have never done before.

Comment: Look, I don't know what you did before, and what has changed since then. It's just what I see from the error you've posted.

Comment: What if you change the port in your MONGO_URL?

Answer (score 0):

It does not just try to connect to mongod, but it installs mongod in a container and tries to bind port 27017 to local interface.

If you already have mongodb installed and prefer to use it instead, you need to disable installation of mongodb in `mup.js`, `mup.json`, or whatever configuration file is being used in your version of mup.